# Facebook login phonegap plugin is not working of some android devices

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I implemented `com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect` plugin in phonegap android app to login using Facebook. It is not working on some device (I have checked the android OS versions, so this issue is not dependent on OS).

On some devices, this plugin is not returning the logged in facebook users information. The strange thing is, it do not work for first time but in second time, it returns data and then in third try, it does not and in forth, it does and so on.

To debug this issue more, I checked the log of plugin itself and find that plugin is returning following error just after getting the user's information from facebook and because of this error, it is not passing those information to phonegap (JS code).

> 09-11 15:23:50.815: I/Web Console(10409):
>   {"errorMessage":"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0x67939250: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol
>   error\nerror:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
>   handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741
>   0x5a17ffc1:0x00000000)","errorType":"null","errorCode":"-1"} at
>   file:///android_asset/www/js/main.js:161

Please let us know, how we can overcome this issue?

Comment: file an issue on the plugin github page

Comment: Hi jcesarmobile, I have posted it on github also. https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1119

Comment: I am also facing similar problem but i haven't checked log of plugin itself